WSL2 Sandbox - Trying to setup a script to build firewall rules on windows 10
I am trying to lock down WSL2 in my environment. I am not able to use the tools in Intune to manage WSL2 because I am not on Windows 11. So, I created a script to pull the IP of the WSL2 Interface and then a separate script to run that creates firewall rules to block all inbound and outbound.
I know that Ubuntu pulls from
$allowedSites = @(
    "archive.ubuntu.com",
    "security.ubuntu.com",
    "ppa.launchpadcontent.net"
)

But even though these sites are whitelisted my WSL2 instance cant seem to pull updates from these services.
Here is the full script for the firewall rules.
EDIT - I updated the script to only apply to the WSL interface. But now the issue is I can't get it to communicate with the DNS or ping any site that's whitelisted.
# Define the path to the persistent log file
$FilePath = "$env:USERPROFILE\wsl_ip.log"
$logFilePath = $FilePath -replace "\.ad", ""
Write-Host "Modified path: $logFilePath"

# Define the allowed sites for Ubuntu updates
$allowedSites = @(
    #"*.archive.ubuntu.com",
    #"*.security.ubuntu.com",
    #"*.ppa.launchpadcontent.net"
    #Allow DNS
    "172.29.144.1", 
    "8.8.8.8"

    #Allow archive.ubuntu.com
    "91.189.91.81",
    "185.125.190.36",
    "185.125.190.39",
    "91.189.91.83",
    "91.189.91.82"

    #Allow security.ubuntu.com
    #"185.125.190.36",
    #"91.189.91.81",
    #"91.189.91.83",
    #"185.125.190.39"

    #Allow ppa.launchpadcontent.net
    "185.125.190.80"

)

# Function to create firewall rule
function Create-FirewallRule {
    param(
        [string]$ipAddress,
        [string[]]$allowedSites,
        [string]$interfaceAlias
    )
    
    # Create a rule to block all inbound traffic for the IP address on the WSL2 interface
    New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block all inbound traffic for WSL IP" `
        -Direction Inbound `
        -RemoteAddress $ipAddress `
        -InterfaceAlias $interfaceAlias `
        -Action Block `
        -Profile Any `
        -Description "Blocks all inbound traffic for WSL IP except for allowed sites"

    # Create a rule to block all outbound traffic for the IP address on the WSL2 interface
    New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block all outbound traffic for WSL IP" `
        -Direction Outbound `
        -RemoteAddress $ipAddress `
        -InterfaceAlias $interfaceAlias `
        -Action Block `
        -Profile Any `
        -Description "Blocks all outbound traffic for WSL IP except for allowed sites"
    
    # Allow outbound traffic to specific sites for Ubuntu updates on the WSL2 interface
    foreach ($site in $allowedSites) {
        New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow outbound traffic to $site" `
            -Direction Outbound `
            -InterfaceAlias $interfaceAlias `
            -RemoteAddress $site `
            -RemotePort 80, 443, 53, 43 `
            -Protocol TCP `
            -Action Allow `
            -Profile Any `
            -Description "Allows outbound traffic to $site"
    }

    # Allow inbound traffic from specific sites for Ubuntu updates on the WSL2 interface
    foreach ($site in $allowedSites) {
        New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow inbound traffic from $site" `
            -Direction Inbound `
            -InterfaceAlias $interfaceAlias `
            -RemoteAddress $site `
            -RemotePort 80, 443, 53, 43 `
            -Protocol TCP `
            -Action Allow `
            -Profile Any `
            -Description "Allows inbound traffic from $site"
    }
}

# Find the WSL2 interface
$wsl2Interface = Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object { $_.InterfaceAlias -like "*WSL*" }

# Check if the WSL2 interface was found
if ($wsl2Interface) {
    # Read the log file and search for the line containing the IP address
    $searchPattern = "ip addr:"
    $ipLine = Select-String -Path $logFilePath -Pattern $searchPattern | Select-Object -First 1

    # Check if a line was found
    if ($ipLine) {
        # Extract the IP address from the line
        $ipLineText = $ipLine.Line
        # Adjust the extraction based on the actual format of the line
        $ipAddress = $ipLineText -replace ".*ip addr:\s*", ""

        Write-Host "Found IP address: $ipAddress"
        
        # Create the firewall rule using the extracted IP address and WSL2 interface alias
        Create-FirewallRule -ipAddress $ipAddress -allowedSites $allowedSites -interfaceAlias $wsl2Interface.InterfaceAlias
    } else {
        Write-Host "No line containing IP address found in the log file."
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "No WSL2 interface found on the system."
}

I try to update with these firewall rules and get a name failure
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpadcontent.net'
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpadcontent.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

But once I remove the rules it works fine so I think I'm just configuring the rules wrong. I think I am setting up the rules to just block traffic to wsl2 which isn't my intention.
I want to setup these rules on the specific interface wsl2 is using.
EDIT - I did modify the code to work on only the interface. Now it just cant do DNS resoultion.

What language is that script?  It doesn't look like any normal POSIX-type shell.  In any case, it looks like your problem is more one of system configuration rather than programming.

Its powershell. I'm deploying the script via Intune to run on Windows to pull data from the WSL install.
I think I figured it out I need to apply the rule to the WSL interface, but I've been applying the rule to the WSL Ip which just blocks all traffic from it on my windows host.
